# How can I convert nvarchar to number and then sum them in reporting services SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, casting

I try to convert from nvarchar to decimal and then sum them. In the db the decimal is a `.` and not a `,`. Might this be a problem?

`=Sum(CDec(Lookup(Fields!RESNO.Value,Fields!machine_ID.Value,Fields!capacity.Value, "table_1")))`